# promise.then() not working when I send in another promise into it

Tags: javascript, node.js, recurly

I have 2 function getAccountInfo() and getAdjustmentsInfo(accountInfo) they both return a new promise. The only different is that the second function needs the information returned from the first function.

I tried to declare these 2 function first, and call them one by one using then(). But it is not working as I expected.

These are the functions, as you can see the second function needs account_code from the first accountInfo object:

```
function getAccountInfo() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        getAccountCallbackFunc((errResponse, response) => {
            if (errResponse) {
                return reject(errResponse);
            }
            resolve(response);
        });
    });
}

function getAdjustmentsInfo(accountInfo) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        getAdjustmentCallbackFunc(accountInfo[0].account_code, function (errResponse, response) {
            if (errResponse) {
                reject(errResponse);
            }
            if (response) {
                resolve(response);
            }
        });
    });
}
```

This is the controller code to call the functions:

```
var accountInfo = {};

getAccountInfo()
    .then(response => {
        accountInfo = response.data.accounts.account;
        console.log(accountInfo);
    })
    .then(getAdjustmentsInfo(accountInfo))
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

So I run the getAccountInfo() function first and run the first then() to saved the account information to the external variable accountInfo. 
Next I run the second then() trying to pass the accountInfo to the second function, which is not working, the second function never got called. Is that something I am missing? Please let me know.

Comment: Seems like you have to understand [return the response from asynchronous call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: Well, you need to send a callback function to `.then()` not another promise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are couple of mistakes in your code. First is that you are not returning anything nor resolving any promise in the line `accountInfo = response.data.accounts.account;console.log(accountInfo);` so the `.then(getAdjustmentsInfo(accountInfo))` will not be called. Secondly, i suppose the first argument to a `.then()` is always a callback with the first argument being something that is returned from the previous Promise.

Your function `getAccountInfo()` returns a promise. When that promise is resolved you can 
directly use that as follows.

```
var accountInfo = {};

getAccountInfo()
     .then(response => {
          accountInfo = response.data.accounts.account;
          console.log(accountInfo);
          getAdjustmentsInfo(accountInfo)
      })
     .then(resultFromPreviousPromise => {
       //Use the resultFromPreviousPromise if wanted else you can skip this .then()
      })
     .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. It worked. I do have one more question, when I run console.log(accountInfo) in the second then(), it prints undefined, is accountInfo = response.data.accounts.account only exist in the scope of first then() ?

Comment: If you are referring to the code that i have put then that should not be the case. The variable `accountInfo` is scoped outside the two functions so both should have access to it and even the second `.then()`. Could you paste the whole code that is causing this behaviors so we can see what might be causing it

Comment: var accountInfo = {};
var adjustmentsInfo = {};



getAccountInfo()
    .then(response => {
        accountInfo = response.data.accounts.account[0];
        //console.log(accountInfo);
        getAdjustmentsInfo(accountInfo)
    })
    .then(response => {
        adjustmentsInfo = response.data.adjustments;
        console.log(accountInfo);
        console.log(adjustmentsInfo);
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err));

Comment: This is the code, the function declare stays the same.

Comment: Nvm it worked, you are right, the part I am showing undefined is not the accountInfo. Thank you !

Comment: Happy to help !!

Answer (score 1):

You are evaluating the `getAdjustmentsInfo` method immediately, since it's not in a callback.  Try:

```
var accountInfo = {};

getAccountInfo()
    .then(response => {
        accountInfo = response.data.accounts.account;
        console.log(accountInfo);
    })
    .then(() => getAdjustmentsInfo(accountInfo))
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

Or even better:

```
var accountInfo = getAccountInfo()
    .then(response => {
        console.log(response.data.accounts.account);
        return response.data.accounts.account;
    })
    .then(account => getAdjustmentsInfo(account))
    .catch(err => {
        console.log(err));
        return {};
    })
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it is very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You call `getAdjustmentsInfo` straight away instead of waiting for `getAccountInfo` and you don't return a `Promise` in the first `then`. I think this is what you mean to do:

```js
getAccountInfo()
    .then(response => {
        accountInfo = response.data.accounts.account;
        return getAdjustmentsInfo(accountInfo)
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

Comment: Thank you for the help, this is very helpful.And it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, I hope it helps.

```
    function getAccountInfo() {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            getAccountCallbackFunc((errResponse, response) => {
                if (errResponse) {
                    return reject(errResponse);
                }
                resolve(response);
            });
        });
    }

    function getAdjustmentsInfo(accountInfo) {
            getAdjustmentCallbackFunc(accountInfo[0].account_code, function (errResponse, response) {
                if (errResponse) {
                    return console.log(errResponse);
                }
                    resolve(response);
            });
    }

    var promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        getAccountInfo()
        .then(response => {
            resolve(response.data.accounts.account);
            console.log(accountInfo);
        })
    }).then(function(data){
        getAdjustmentsInfo(data);
    }).catch(function(err){console.log(err)});
```